# ImportError: No module named _ssl occurring even when /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so is available fc18

Tags: python, https, openssl

I'm seeing urlopen error when I try to do communication on HTTPS

```
<urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

I searched for this error and found that this issue is related to ssl. I need to have _ssl.so file in my /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/ folder. But the file is already present. I try to import ssl in python console and see the import error for ssl.

Here is the information of file

```
$ ll /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
-r-xr-xr-x. 1 root root 38544 Aug  9  2012 /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
```

And here is what I'm seeing on python console

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Apr 14 2014, 02:00:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
>>> import ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named _ssl
```

Can anybody please help me figure out the issue?

Comment: Have you installed openssl?

Comment: Yes openssl is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out the issue. There were 2 python installations. The installation i was checking for openssl lib, contained the file. But by default other installation of python was being used for running the programs. Once I switched to correct python installation, the error went away.